# Compare two pairs folders in one instance of program

Tags: merge

I would like to run `Araxis Merge` via Windows command line (`.bat`) for comparation two and more pairs folders but i don't understand is it possible?

In [official documentation](https://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-windows/command-line.en) they tells that i can run it only for three files in the same time or only two folders. But they didn't tell that it is (not) possible for using different tabs for each pair

The [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWw5P.jpg) below for clearifying my question

Thx.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see it. but in globaly it's the same documentation. I have read docs in help (F1), but for this question i have found web-documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge Support Service answered me:

> To display multiple comparisons in a single instance of Merge, you
>   need only call the compare.exe command-line tool multiple times, for
>   example:
>
> compare.exe folderA folderB compare.exe folder1 folder2
>
> The above would result in a single instance of Merge displaying a
>   folder comparison for folderA and folderB in one tab, and folder1 and
>   folder2 is a second tab.
>
> I hope this helps to clarify things, if not, please do not hesitate to
>   contact us again.